# Ag grid both custom and default header renderers Angular

Tags: angular, ng-grid

Is it possible to use default and custom header renderer based on some boolean flag?
Didn't find solution here
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/
In their example you can use custom header, but you can not switch between them.
use case - bulk buttons in header instead of column names when you select a row

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params to header component and show and hide icon base on params value.

```
headerComponentParams : {
        showIcon: true/false/somefunction // show icon in headerComponent base on this param value
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but if I want to totally change header. Like, hide all column headers and draw 2 buttons when selection is active?

Comment: well in that case Set the header height to zero.      <ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [headerHeight]="VariableForHeight">
 </ag-grid-angular>

Comment: initially set [headerHeight]="20"  and hide button and then set [headerHeight]="0" and show button